# Consolidate tags 11ty & eleventy into eleventy

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It's pretty clear they both refer to the same thing: a static-site generator that goes by both names.

- There are 164 questions tagged `eleventy`
- There are only 15 questions tagged `11ty`

I manually reviewed all 15 `11ty` tags (using an incognito browser, to bypass my regular filters), and every one of them is unambiguously concerned with the static-site generator:

- several have links to the official site
- a few have code samples (or links to code) that exhibit the tech
- several have both tags, which I interpret as confusion on the part of authors, who don't know which tag will lead to the right audience

I propose we consolidate into `eleventy`, because it currently dominates the population.

Comment: what abou a synonym which would make more sense

Comment: _“using an incognito browser, to bypass my regular filters”_ — You could also search `[11ty] is:q`, which ignores filters.

Comment: @nbk That’s what is meant by [consolidating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consolidate#Verb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merged and synonymized:

**[eleventy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eleventy) ← [11ty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/11ty)**

I also updated the tag wiki excerpt to include the abbreviation "11ty" (in case people are looking for that), as well as to hopefully clarify that the tag should not be applied simply in cases where one is *using* Eleventy, but only where the usage of it is germane to the question itself.

Thanks for doing the legwork on this one to review the questions in advance, *before* posting the request. That really saves moderators a lot of time, not to mention helps get these actioned more quickly. (Of course, it's small potatoes when it's only 15 questions. Imagine when there are eleventy!)